# js "Void function return value is used" meaning

Tags: jquery

I have the following code where the alert is working but when I select the option with the given id, nothing happens.
JS:

```
var connType = (function() {
  alert("test");
  $("#connType").change(function() {
    if ($(this).css("value") === 2 {
      $(".mgconn").css("display", "block");
    }
  });
})();
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="connType" name="connection_type">
      <option selected value="1">first op</option>
      <option value="2">something</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row mgconn" style="display: none">
     <div class="col-md-3">
          <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" type="text"/>
                                           
                                    
</div>
```

In ide I have the void function highlight, and I don't understand what it means. I don't see what return I should have in here. I'm sorry for the simplicity of my question, I realize it must be something basic and I can't figure really what to look after in the console, to test it.

Comment: are you inserting this literal? i guess the js should at least be inside a script tag

Comment: Why does your code contain all these backticks? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I've reformatted the question, with the assumption the the "back ticks" / "literal" was just OPs attempt to format as code within the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: First thing you are using jquery functions but jquery not include and secondly you are not doing anything on change

Comment: @UmarFarooqueKhan it's a snippet, no need to "include jquery" in the question - if jquery was missing, OP would get $ is undefined, which they've not mentioned (maybe not checked the console).    The question also isn't about the on change "not working" - both of these are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: alert will work even if you don't include JQuery while no other stuff @freedomn-m

Comment: @UmarFarooqueKhan oh yes, good spot.   Op would get an error after this.   They're not reporting an error.

Comment: You could also remove the IIFE wrapper `(function() { })()` if your intention is only to assign an event - put it at the end before `</body>` or wrap in doc.ready.  If you have other reason for IIFE then keep it.

Comment: Thank you all! I have added the missing div with mgconn class to this post.  Also I was thinking the problem might be because the div doesn't exist in the moment the function runs...or something like that.

Comment: **Please confirm:** are you asking why your `change` event doesn't work *or* are you asking about the **IDE warning** (as per the question title).  SO questions should only contain one specific question.   Assuming you *do* have `<script src=jquery.js>` and you *do not* have any errors on the console (F12, console) then your code, as provided, works fine.   https://jsfiddle.net/ogtvx5Lj/

Comment: I thought the IDE warning and the not working event are related. I have found out that the function was loading before the html because I have another file where is a load() event for the js and I was supposed to call the function there. If the IIFE is removed. the ide warning disappears. But the function is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE warning is because you are assigning the result of a function that returns undefined to a variable.

It's not a javascript error, it's just an IDE warning.  Depending on your IDE, you'll probably get the same warning with this code:

```
function example() {
}
var x = example()
```

You can confirm this with `console.log(connType)` (===undefined) in your code.

You can safely remove the `var connType =` part of your code and have the IIFE run without needing to assign to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that the function was loading before the html because I have another file where is a load() event for the js and I was supposed to call the function there. If the IIFE is removed. the ide warning disappears.

Comment: If in doubt, wrap your event handlers inside a doc.ready - it will run immediately if the DOM is already loaded or wait until it is, so position of code is not so important: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div class="form-group row">
             <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="connType" 
                   name="connection_type">
                   <option selected>first op</option>
                   <option value="something">something</option>
                </select>
             </div>
             <div class="mgconn" style="display:none"> Show on change</div>
          </div>
          <script>
             $("#connType").change(function(){
                 if($(this).val() === "something"){
                     $(".mgconn").css("display","block");
                  }else{
                     $(".mgconn").css("display","none");
                  }
             });
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: In question there is no mgconn class that you are displaying, here in my answer added the same class now its working fine.

Comment: @freedomn-m exactly i added working example and also fulfilling the need

Comment: Can you add an explanation how this fixes OP question of what `Void function return value is used` means - other than simply removing the IIFE?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?